# Does dynamic programming improve complexity for regex with Kleene star

Tags: regex, algorithm

Leetcode problem for regex matching including a Kleene star: https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/.

The solution suggests dynamic programming to memoize solutions to sub-problems. I can't think of a normal example where dynamic programming helps, e.g. that that the sub-problems are encountered more than once in the recursion tree. The only cases I can think of are degenerate ones where the regex can be simplified.

For example, if the text is `"aab"` and the regex is `"a*a*"`, then you do encounter the same call twice: `match("ab", "a*")`. Here are the two branches of the tree where that occurs:

```
match("aab", "a*a*")
match("aab", "a*")
match("ab", "a*")  // occurs here

match("aab", "a*a*")
match("ab", "a*a*")
match("ab", "a*")  // also occurs here
```

However, you would not use `"a*a*"`, you can simplify this regex to `"a*"`, in which case I don't see any improvement on the regular recursive solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*a.*ab.*` on a long string of just `a`s.  You can make naive recursion as slow as you like on a failure to match.  If you allow parentheses, you can make it take exponential time to fail to match.

Comment: *"The only cases I can think of are degenerate ones where the regex can be simplified."*: so are you assuming that LeetCode would only run test cases with expressions that cannot be simplified? Why would you assume that?

Comment: I'm not assuming anything about what Leetcode does to test your code, I'm just curious if this applies to non-degenerate cases. I'm going to try out the example btilly gave above! Thanks both!